# Confluence table synced to Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, synchronization, confluence

I would like to link a table that exists as a page in Confluence to my Google Sheets so that I don't have to manually update the latter when the former changes, and I'm having a heck of a time finding a decent solution. I should mention I have zero programming knowledge.

I assumed I could just use IMPORTHTML. No dice, since Confluence is password protected. Thought I found a solution with awesome-table.com but looks like the only Atlassian sync is with Jira and not Confluence. Wondering if anyone has success with this?

Answer (score 0):

@sandy,
If not using some existing 3-rd party apps like
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/search?query=google%20sheets , I suppose the most flexible option is to use APIs of both to do what you need: get data from  page table with REST API (https://docs.atlassian.com/ConfluenceServer/rest/8.4.0/) and send it with GSheets API to Google Sheets.